# How do I install baseboards behind bifold closet doors?

Tags: baseboard, closet

I'm remodeling a house and I pulled out the old baseboard and carpet and replaced with hardwood and now I'm putting on the baseboards.  I have several closet openings with bifold doors (I haven't installed them yet) and I'm wondering how I should approach baseboard between the bifold door and the closet opening to hide the flooring's expansion gap.

How do I install baseboard between the edge of the bifold door and the closet opening?

Comment: It sounds like your door openings drywall wrapped?

Answer (score 4):

You don't. Either stop the baseboard at the corner and live with the gap, or frame the opening with baseboard or molding and overhang the edge.

Notice how in this picture you can't see the metal track at the top, and you also can't see the gap between the outer left/right edges of the doors and the wall. That's because the molding overhangs the wall by 1/4 to 1/2 inch.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your bifolds have molding around them then that should cover any expansion gap.

If they don't have molding I would not add molding if the doors fit because you would need to cut every door vertically to adjust for molding depth.

An easy solution is continue trim throughout the closet and notch out the outer corners of the closet doors.